# Why does py command result in errors when python3 command doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, pip

I can't seem to find an answer or solution to this anywhere so if there is one please quote or link it here. When running python in the command line, if I do `python3 -m pip install aiohttp` it installs aiohttp just fine. However, if I do `py -m pip install aiohttp` it gives me install errors because it seems to have trouble "building wheel" and I have no idea why.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark - I'm using windows 11.

Comment: type ```py --version``` and ```python3 --version``` are they both python3

Comment: @EthanArmstrong - They are both python3; however, `python3` results in 3.10.4 and I've just downloaded the newest alpha of python, so `py` results in 3.11.0a7

Answer (score 2):

You might have multiple python 3 versions installed.
Wheel might be in one but not the other version.
py uses the latest version installed. python3 might not.
In cmd, type each command separately,  in the first lines it will display the python version each command is using.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem with wheel itself because it only fails to build the wheel for specific packages. For example, it's currently consistently failing to build the wheel for `aiohttp`, `frozenlist`, and `yarl`. I was able to install `asyncio` and `ujson` just fine.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps put a message on the gihub page of aiohttp stating it doesnt build the wheel under python3.11.0a7

Answer (score 1):

`python3` and `py` are different things, `python3` is calling the **python3 third-party library** then after access it then -m then call `pip` module so it’s `python3 -m pip` then what we need to do is installing packages so it’s install then type what you need :)

so the whole command:

```
python3 -m pip install aiohttp
```